# Sending multiple Set-Cookie headers with AWS Lambda and AWS API Gateway not working

Tags: cookies, aws-lambda, https, aws-api-gateway, setcookie

I'm trying to send multiple Set-Cookie headers via a AWS Lambda Function integrated with an HTTP API from API Gateway but I cant manage to do that in a non-trash way.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html

The documented way form official documentation doesnt seems to work

If i send two ore more Set-Cookie inside "headers", only the last one is actually sent

If i send an "headers" with one Set-Cookie with an array of values, one for each cookie, the fetch results in 500 - Internal Server Error, but the lambda logs dont show any error

If i send an "cookie" with an array of strings as values for cookies, as shown in the documentation, it also doesnt work

I've read that some people manage to do that by using different Set-Cookie upper-case and lower-case variations, but i wish i could avoid bad "work arounds" like this, so I didnt even tried.